# how to protect uploads folder with .htaccess to only allow images in wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a question i need to protect site from uploading and/or executing any scripts or files other than images only in a wordpress site.

But i have tried few variations with .htaccess file and no success.

The wordpress have wp-content/uploads folder where uploads are stored. And inside that it's sorted based on year / month combination in folders. I used this example from wordpress site but it somehow locks entire folder and i can't even see the images.

```
<Files ^(*.jpeg|*.jpg|*.png|*.gif)>
   order deny,allow
   deny from all
</Files>
```

So is there a working way on making it available to upload and sort images inside wp-content/upload folders and later on access them. I think the problem is that there are subfolders sinside uploads or i am wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So an htaccess solution won't affect what they can upload but will recursively effect access for all subdirectories.

```
RewriteEngine on
#if the file does not have one of theses extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$
#then it should be marked as forbidden.
RewriteRule .*$ - [F]
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks , it's exactly what i needed. I didn't had a chance to test it until now.